# Understanding Identity theorem proof in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

**Identity theorem**
Let $f$ be holomorphic functions on some domain $D\subset\mathbb{C}$, and let $S$ be the set of all zeros of $f$ which has a limit point in $D$. Then $f$ is identically zero in $D$.

Proof in short: Let $a$ be limit point of $S$ this means that there exist a sequence $a_n$ of zeros such that $a_n\rightarrow a$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Then $f(z)$ is identically zero on the disc $|z-a|<R$.

To complete the proof we have to show that $f(z)$ is identically zero on the whole domain $D$. For this purpose, we decomposed $D$ into two sets:

$E_1$=$z \in D$, where $z$ is a limit point of S

$E_2$=$z \in D$, where $z\not\in S$

**Doubt 1** I am having difficulty to understand how the sets $E_1$ and $E_2$ are defined? Could someone explain me through example If possible?

$2$ How to show that set $E_1$ and $E_2$ are open?
Book that I follow says that since $z\in E_1$ is a limit point of $S$, $f(z)$ is identically zero in a neighborhood of $z$. From here how can we deduce that each point of $E_1$ is an interior point of $E_1$

Thanks in advance. For any queries related to this question please feel free to put comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E_1$ is the set of limit points of $S$. For instance, if $S$ is an open disk, then $E_1$ is a closed disk.

$E_2$ are all points in your domain which are not in $S$. Meaning - all points on which $f$ is non-zero.

$E_1$ is open by the argument you wrote - for any $z\in E_1$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $z$ on which $f$ is identically $0$. In particular, all of the points in $U$ are also limit points of $S$ (which means that it is open, since you see that each point has a neighborhood contained in the set). Why is this true? Since $f$ is identically $0$ around each point in $U$, so you can get arbitrarily close to them via points on which $f$ is $0$.

Moreover, $E_2$ is open as the continuous preimage of the open set $\mathbb C - \{0\}$.

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask more.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one more query about openness of $E_2$. Could you elaborate more to this.

Comment: @srijan Your function is analytic, and inparticular continuous. The preimage of an open set under a contonuous function is by definition always open. Just make sure that $\mathbb C - \{0\}$ is open to obtain the result (hint - its complement is closed).

Comment: Thank you so much